# Run Meteor app with Supervisord

Tags: meteor, supervisord

I want to run [Telescope](http://telesc.pe/), an app build with [Meteor](https://www.meteor.com/). But when I launch it with Supervisord I have this error in log file :

```
/usr/local/bin/meteor: line 34: HOME: unbound variable
```

This is my supervisord config file :

```
[program:news]
directory=/srv/telescope
command=/usr/local/bin/meteor
autorestart=true
redirect_stderr=true
```

How to run a Meteor app with Supervisord ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When supervisor starts process, it doesn't sets environment variables. Looks like meteor or Telescope requires HOME variable to be set. You can fix that by using `environment` in your supervisor config:

```
[program:news]
directory=/srv/telescope
command=/usr/local/bin/meteor
autorestart=true
redirect_stderr=true
environment=HOME="/home/ubuntu"
```

You can read more about it in [supervisor configuration](http://supervisord.org/configuration.html) and [subprocess environment](http://supervisord.org/subprocess.html#subprocess-environment).